# Search in a List of List Object in C#

Tags: c#, string, linq, list

I am having a List of List object in C#. I would like to search this list using ´findall´ method of LINQ.

Here is the code I am using :

```
String searchString = "Keyword";

List<IntVector> newList = UserData.FindAll(s =>
                            s.ClientName.IndexOf(searchString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0 ||
                            s.CustomerID.IndexOf(searchString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0 ||
                            s.AddInfo.IndexOf(searchString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0 ||
                            s.MobileNo.IndexOf(searchString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0).ToList();
```

However, I am not able to search the nested list. One of the member of ´UserData´ is ´CustomerInfo´ which itself is a list of String.

Any idea how to do it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

First, instead of repeating same code many times, I'd create extension method

```
public static bool IgnoreCaseContains(this string s, string value)
{
    return s.IndexOf(value, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0;
}
```

Now use `Where` and `Any` operators:

```
var query = from u in UserData
            where u.ClientName.IgnoreCaseContains(searchString) ||
                  u.CustomerID.IgnoreCaseContains(searchString) ||
                  u.AddInfo.IgnoreCaseContains(searchString) ||
                  u.MobileNo.IgnoreCaseContains(searchString) || 
                  u.CustomerInfo.Any(i => i.IgnoreCaseContains(searchString))
            select u;
```

BTW `FindAll` returns list, so you don't need to create copy of that list with `ToList` call.

---

One step further, you can move all this complex search into [user search specification](http://martinfowler.com/apsupp/spec.pdf), or even in another extension method:

```
public static bool Matches(this IntVector user, string searchString)
{
    return user.ClientName.IgnoreCaseContains(searchString) ||
           user.CustomerID.IgnoreCaseContains(searchString) ||
           user.AddInfo.IgnoreCaseContains(searchString) ||
           user.MobileNo.IgnoreCaseContains(searchString) ||
           user.CustomerInfo.Any(i => i.IgnoreCaseContains(searchString))
}
```

In this case your code will look like

```
List<IntVector> newList = UserData.FindAll(u => u.Matches(searchString));
```

Or

```
var spec = new UserSearchSpecification("keyword");
List<IntVector> newList = UserData.FindAll(u => spec.IsSatisfiedBy(u));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Any()`extension method to see if any of the string in list of strings matches your keyword-

```
 List<IntVector> newList = UserData.FindAll(s =>
                           s.ClientName.IndexOf(searchString, 
                                  StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0 ||
                           s.CustomerID.IndexOf(searchString, 
                                  StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0 ||
                           s.AddInfo.IndexOf(searchString,
                                  StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0 ||
                           s.MobileNo.IndexOf(searchString, 
                              StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0 ||
                           s.CustomerInfo.Any(t => t.IndexOf(searchString, 
                             StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) >= 0);
```